# when or why using mysql AS and USING?

Tags: mysql

Can anyone explain to me why they use `AS id` and `AS r2` and `USING id` on the codes :

```
SELECT id, username FROM friendship JOIN (SELECT CEIL(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM friendship)) AS id) AS r2 USING (id);
```

I just want to know the purpose of using them, why using them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The As is just to create an Alias for the subquery, that way you can use that same alias 'id' with the using command.

Basically the query wants the friendship table to join the subquery on the id column, since the subquery only returns one result it can join with the id column in the friendship table.

Comment: why need to create an alias? The subquery will returns the same one result too even without using As id, they the subquery still can join the id column in friendship table if without writing As id, so why they need to write As id? What is the different with As id and without As id?

Comment: @Zac1987 It is true that both will have the id column, however because the join clause is not with an existing table but with a subquery result you need to specify the join condition. I am pretty sure it will not work otherwise.

Comment: so `As id` is to specify the `JOIN` condition? Usually we specify the `JOIN` condition like `ON table1.id = table2.id`;
so `AS id` is just the same like `table2.id` ?

Comment: @Zac1987 As Id is just to identify the result of the subquery,  and yes we are using it to specify the join condition, using is a shortcut for join on table.id = mysubquery.id. Yes in this scenario it would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

OscarMk already explained the AS, but the USING is the equivalent of `ON table1.id = table2.id`. By using USING (a bit redundant here...), your RDBMS basically merge the columns into a single one, which means you don't have to tell your RDBMS if you want the column from table1 or table2. Simple example :

```
SELECT table1.id
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
    ON table1.id = table2.id;


SELECT id
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
    USING (id);
```

Those queries are equivalent. If you had forgotten to use table1.id in the first query, your RDBMS would have raised an error.

You can usually do a NATURAL JOIN instead of a INNER JOIN, and not use a USING or ON clause at all (that's what NATURAL JOIN are for)

Comment: in my case, both are the same table, why need to join the id in a same table since the id is the same?